# ng-bootstrap not working (angular2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap in my Angular2 project using ng-bootstrap.

Following their instructions, I added the bootstrap css file, mapped @ng-bootstrap in my systemJS config, installed ng-bootstrap and added their main module to my root module:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';

import { NgbModule }            from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent }      from './header/header.component';
import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But when I try to create a simple messaging board template, it doesn't work as expected. When I leave the Ngbmodule out, nothing seems to change.

Weirdly enough, when I change from bootstrap 4 css to bootstrap 3.3.6 css, a lot more is working as expected, yet simple things like text-areas still aren't styled at all.

Am I doing something wrong during the installation of ng-bootstrap? Any help would be welcome.

**UPDATE**

This is the markup I'm using and an example of my output: http://plnkr.co/edit/A9DySwR3PBNJShRFi27Q?p=preview

While this is the result I used to achieve on angular-1 projects with the same code:
http://prnt.sc/db9azv

Comment: "But when I try to create a simple messaging board template, it doesn't work as expected. When I leave the Ngbmodule out, nothing seems to change. " - it is not very clear what do you mean by "doesn't work as expected" here. Could you be more specific? In any case here is a minimal plunker showing a working ng-bootstrap component: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKVVBdHJxnC0X67UjilM?p=preview - try to reproduce your problem using this plunker as a starting point.

Comment: `ng-bootstrap` would only work with `bootstrap-4` version.. You could checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/998)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the example! This makes it a lot clearer for me. I'm also starting to think this behaviour I'm expecting might not be correct.
This is the markup I'm using: http://plnkr.co/edit/3vpHSIGWH6i8M0QOJdPv?p=preview and this is what I'm expecting: http://prntscr.com/db9azv

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar yes I have read about that, which I why I said it is strange that it works better with 3.3.6 than it does with 4.0!

Comment: @MaxTaylor No, I'm working on it from couple of weeks. I had situation where nothing was working with `BS3` version. And everything was working fine with `BS4`

Comment: It is pure CSS pb, nothing to do with `ng-bootstrap` - posted and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to be specific to the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io project but rather to the Bootstrap's 4 CSS only. Based on your example I think that you just have a typo in your CSS class name - it should be `form-control` and *not* `form control`.

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hfvCwMistZdIWUlOAthM?p=preview

Comment: Yeah I just figured out they dropped "panels" in Bootstrap 4. That typo was also part of the problem, making me think it wasn't working all together. Anyway thanks for your help, I guess I'll have start learning about cards!